# A little help with the unmixedness theorem?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

I have two smooth subvarieties $Y$ and $Z$ of a smooth variety $X$.  Their intersection $Y \cap Z$ has two irreducible components, both of the expected dimension and generically reduced.  I want to conclude that $Y \cap Z$ is reduced by the unmixedness theorem.  Is this right?

Comment: I am not sure what you meant by unmixed theorem, but I think generically reduced + unmixed = reduced. 

Comment: In view of Jason's answer, it is probably worth noting that unmixed = Serre's condition $(S_1)$. 

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Dear Nick -- First of all, if a ring satisfies Serre's criterion $S1$ and is "generically reduced", i.e., the stalk at every generic point is a field, then the ring is reduced.  This is explained, for instance at the top of p. 183, Section 23 of Matsumura's "Commutative Ring Theory".  Second, if $Y$, resp. $Z$ is a closed subscheme of a regular, locally Noetherian scheme which is itself regular, then it is everywhere locally cut out by a regular sequence, cf. Theorem 21.2(ii), p. 171, of Matsumura.  Finally, if also $Y\cap Z$ has the "expected codimension", then $Y\cap Z$ is also locally cut out by a regular sequence, and thus Cohen-Macaulay, by Theorem 17.4, p. 135 of Matsumura. (In fact it is even LCI by Theorem 21.2 again.)  A Cohen-Macaulay scheme satisfies Serre's criterion $Sn$ for every integer $n\geq 0$.  Thus your scheme $Y\cap Z$ is reduced.

Comment: Thanks, Jason (and Hailong) - I haven't really used this Cohen-Macaulay stuff before, so I wanted to make sure I had my head screwed on straight.